# Yahoo Boss API query

Tags: c#, metadata, yahoo, yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api

I am using C# to call Yahoo Boss API and to retrieve metadata e.g. open graph information from url. Before thinking about any metatags I am simply querying a word within a url:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://yboss.yahooapis.com/ysearch/web?q=Besieged&format=json&url=http://www.nytimes.com/2012/08/24/business/global/chinas-economy-besieged-by-buildup-of-unsold-goods.html");
```

In the above query I am quering the word Besieged on the webpage refenced by the url however it does not give any results.

Any suggestions how to build a Yahoo Boss query that retrieves metadata for url?

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/?)

Comment: I updated the question with a query example!